# passing an array in call by value

Tags: c

I have a problem calling a function by passing the value,here is the test code

```
#include <stdio.h>

void sample(int b[3][2])
{
  int t;
  for(t=0;t<3;t++)
  {
    printf("value is =%d\n",b[t][0]);
  }
}

int main()
{

  int d[3][2]={(2,3),(4,2),(5,2)};

  sample(d[3][2]);
}
```

I get an error saying the reference type should be (*)[2] and not 'int'. What is the right way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
sample(d);
```

instead of:

```
sample(d[3][2]);
```

`d[3][2]` is simply the value of an element of the array and this is not what you want to pass.

Also:

```
int d[3][2]={(2,3),(4,2),(5,2)};
```

this is not how you initialize an array.

```
int d[3][2]={{2, 3}, {4,2}, {5, 2}};
```

is the correct way.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot pass an array by value in C: arrays are passed by address. If you want to pass an array by value, wrap it in a `struct`:

```
struct with_array {
    int b[3][2];
};
void sample(struct with_array s) {
    ...
}
int main() {
    struct with_array arg = {.b = {{2,3},{4,2} ,{5,2}}};
    sample(arg);
}
```

P.S. If you do not need to pass by value, your approach can be fixed, too. You need to follow the right syntax on initialization, and pass the whole array to `sample`, rather than accessing one of its elements (which is also beyond the bounds of the array).

Comment: In C, there is only call by value!

Comment: @haccks Except sometimes the value being passed is that of an address :-)

Comment: @haccks Passing by value implies copying semantics. Arrays do not get copied unless they are embedded in a `struct`. When you copy an address of an array, you cannot claim that the array is being passed by value, only that the address is passed by value (which is correct, but not too helpful).

Comment: In C everything is passed by value. Array object decays to pointer to first element, but it is still passed by value (if you try to modify that pointer in callee changes in the caller would be lost).

Comment: @mfxm "it is still passed by value" the problem here is that the word "it" does not refer to an array, it is referred to a pointer. It is pointer that's passed by value, not an array. Like I explained above, passing by value requires copying semantic. You can say that whatever gets copied is passed by value. When you pass an array, the pointer gets copied, so the pointer is passed by value. The array does not get copied, so the array is not passed by value.

Answer (score 1):

You can either wrap array in struct or use pointer to array.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void sample(int (*b)[3][2])
{
  for (int t = 0; t < 3; t++)
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        printf("%d\n", (*b)[t][i]);
    }
  }
}

int main(void)
{

  int d[3][2]={{1,2}, {3,4}, {5,6} };

  sample(&d);
}
```

By the way, your code has bug `int d[3][2]={(2,3),(4,2),(5,2)};` here `(2,3`) is a comma expression which yields 3 - this is not an array.

Answer (score 0):

`d[3][2]` points to an not existing element in array `d`. Use:

```
sample(d);
```

Answer (score 0):

Compiler interpret

```
void sample(int b[3][2])
```

as

```
void sample(int (*b)[2])
```

((The reason behind this is that arrays decay into pointers **once**, it doesn't happen recursively. An array of arrays decays into a pointer to an array.))

Pass can `d` which is of `int (*)[2]` type.

```
sample(d);
```

instead of passing `d[3][2]` which is of type `int` and also this array element is out of array bound.